# Equal resistance in parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

If I have a parallel circuit where there are two bulbs with the exact same properties (resistance etc) then will the current going through the two branches be guaranteed to be equal or will it be random?

I know this is probably a very simple question but I just can't find a simple answer online.

Comment: If you do a web search on your title there are a multitude of sites which will give you information for doing the calculation. Don't expect an answer. Look for information to help you calculate or conceptualize. I don't know what you mean by "guaranteed" or "random."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a parallel circuit, the potential difference across the resistors are equal. The current is divided based on the value of the resistances.

In your case, the **current will be *equally* divided in the two bulbs**.

Consider the potential difference to be $V$ and the resistance of each bulb be $R$. So, the current in each of the bulbs be $\frac{V}{R}$.

This has been done for a 100% ideal case. In practical cases, there will always be difference in resistances even for bulbs of sane rating owing to losses in power during supply, and several other factors.

Answer (score 0):

The bulbs are made by a manufacturer to a specification within a certain tolerance which may be resistance of bulb at working voltage or working current or working temperature $\pm 1\%, \pm 2\%, \pm 5\%$ etc of the specified value.
The currents passing through bulbs connected in parallel are therefore not going to be exactly equal.
If you want the currents through your bulbs to be within a certain range of values you will have to find appropriate bulbs by trial and error.